Short notation for $(u_1u_2\cdots u_n)' =u_1'u_2\cdots u_n + u_1u_2'\cdots u_n+\cdots+u_1u_2\cdots u_n'$
Looking for a Short hand notation for $(u_1u_2\cdots u_n)' =u_1'u_2\cdots u_n + u_1u_2'\cdots u_n+\cdots+u_1u_2\cdots u_n'$
Or some type of a rolling signifier notation that might already exists in combinatorics.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50932/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/880189/42969

$$\sum_i u_i'\prod_{j\not = i} u_j$$
